# Remove element id

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I am trying to fix our Google trusted stores integration which suddenly stopped working
I have all necessary fields generated only problem is when it iterates through the order items, it adds an HTML element id to each item, see code below

```
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;" translate="no" class="notranslate">
  <!-- start order and merchant information -->
  <span id="gts-o-id">108565</span>


  <span id="gts-o-domain">www.test.com</span>
  <span id="gts-o-email">test@test.com</span>


  <span id="gts-o-country">US</span>
  <span id="gts-o-currency">USD</span>


  <span id="gts-o-total">5.89</span>
  <span id="gts-o-discounts">-0</span>


  <span id="gts-o-shipping-total">0</span>
  <span id="gts-o-tax-total">0.39</span>


  <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">2014-09-19</span>


  <span id="gts-o-has-preorder">N</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-digital">N</span>


  <!-- end order and merchant information -->

   <!-- start repeated item specific information -->

  <span class="gts-item" id="mf140">


    <span class="gts-i-name" id="mf141">product</span>
    <span class="gts-i-price" id="mf142">5.5</span>


    <span class="gts-i-quantity" id="mf143">1</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id" id="mf144">testsku</span>


    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id" id="mf145">111111</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country" id="mf146">US</span>


    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language" id="mf147">en</span>
  </span>

  <!-- end repeated item specific information -->


</div>
```

This is breaking the Trusted Stores, and not sending a Popup to submit info I think. Below is the output from the Google Trusted stores test tool

```
Unknown fields specified in the order confirmation module
How to Fix: Remove or correct the following fields: “mf140”.
Learn more
```

I'm not sure where this is even coming from, so don't know how to fix it.
Below is our success.phtml code for gts

```
<?php
    $orderId = $this->getOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
    $backorder = false; // some backorder logic
    $download = false; // some download logic


    $today = date("Y-m-d"); // some logic to determine ship date
    $shipDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today)) . " +1 week");
?>
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;">
  <!-- start order and merchant information -->
  <span id="gts-o-id"><?php echo $orderId; ?></span>


  <span id="gts-o-domain">www.test.com</span>
  <span id="gts-o-email"><?php echo htmlentities($order->getCustomerEmail()); ?></span>


  <span id="gts-o-country"><?php echo htmlentities($address->getCountryId()); ?></span>
  <span id="gts-o-currency">USD</span>


  <span id="gts-o-total"><?php echo(round($order->getGrandTotal(),2)); ?></span>
  <span id="gts-o-discounts">-<?php echo(round($order->getDiscountAmount(),2)); ?></span>


  <span id="gts-o-shipping-total"><?php echo(round($order->getShippingAmount(),2)); ?></span>
  <span id="gts-o-tax-total"><?php echo($order->getGrandTotal() - $order->getSubtotal()); ?></span>


  <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date"><?php echo date('Y-m-d', $shipDate); ?></span>


  <span id="gts-o-has-preorder"><?php echo $backorder ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-digital">N</span>


  <!-- end order and merchant information -->

<?php foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item): ?>   <!-- start repeated item specific information -->

  <span class="gts-item">


    <span class="gts-i-name"><?php echo htmlentities($item->getName()); ?></span>
    <span class="gts-i-price"><?php echo(round($item->getBasePrice(),2)); ?></span>


    <span class="gts-i-quantity"><?php echo (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(); ?></span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id"><?php echo $item->getSku(); ?></span>


    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id">11111</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">US</span>


    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">en</span>
  </span>
  <?php endforeach; ?>  
  <!-- end repeated item specific information -->


</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can remove that for that specific element

Comment: Did you add any new javascript library to your site recently?

Comment: Yup that's what it was, when you said JS library, I relized mf prefix stands for Mouseflow probably. Removing Mouseflow code worked. Now I have to figure out with Mouseflow WTH is going on. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue seem to be cause by a javascript library that is automatically assigning id to each element.

To fix either remove that js library or write a Javascript to auto remove all id from span tags within `gts-order`. Since gts-order is a hidden element it should not affect this library.

Assuming jQuery is included.

```
// Please not this must script must be executed after that library and before Google trusted stores js 
$('#gts-order span').removeAttr('id');
```